# Redux global solution for Cannot read property of undefined in mapStateToProps if store is not yet hydrated

Tags: reactjs, redux, lazy-evaluation

After migrating to react redux land, I'm in love.. yet my heart breaks every time i try to render a route and gets a Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in the mapStateToProps function which is trying to extract a slice of state that is not loaded yet.

Example:

```
state = { posts:{ blog : {byId:{},ids:[]}, wall: {byId:{},ids{} } };
```

Say I do fetch all data from the server once the app starts up "index.js entry point". Based on the assumption that all data is loaded, I code multiple components to filter this data and work on it.

Trouble happens when a user opens the app and navigates too fast to a page where the data is not yet loaded. Then I get the hated error of "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Example:

```
//route ::/posts/blog/1 has something like this
export default connect(
  (state,prop)=>({
    postId: state.posts.blog.byId[props.params.id].id
  }))(props=><div>Post Id:{props.postId}</div>);
```

Now this components if loaded before blog store is populated it will give an error.

An option is to return a placeholder to connect and check first that post is loaded, or to use a magical proxy in initialState

```
initialState.blog = {byId:new Proxy({},{get:(obj,name)=>(name in obj)?obj[name]:{}}),ids[]}
//this will suppress error by returing an empty object if undefined byId
```

Is there any way i can REQUIRE a component to load its data by dispatching an action for example before it even renders?

What i want is something like what propTypes does except that it will defer loading the component or its connect function until the store confirms that it has finished loading.

Idea from propTypes:

```
Component.propTypes = {
  dispatch:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

This will give an error if dispatch is not supplied as a prop for component
i want something similar but for store.

Example:

```
Component.requireData = (state)=>({
  posts.blog:<placeHolder actionToDispatch="POST/BLOG/LOAD"/>, //if not posts.blog.isLoaded render placeholdercomponent insteed.
});
```

So it happens automagically if the required data is not loaded yet, the component will not render, and the placeholder will render in place dispatching an action that load the required missing data.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a component's `render` is called, it means the parent decided the component should exist. `mapStateToProps` is free to examine the state in any detail it needs to and produce any props from it as it sees fit. If a part of the state is missing, it can substitute some other props.

Some part of your system will have to decide when a place holder should be rendered rather than the data presentation component. The component that decides this may be the component itself or a parent. If it's a parent then you can make this component reusable.

No matter which way you turn this, you have to code the part that decides if all the data is ready. There's no magic. At the very least you'd need to pass a field name, but a function would be more flexible. At this point you may as well plug this function into the `connect` directly.

As such it seems to me that just writing a simple reusable parent component that takes a boolean prop that decides whether to show the child or a placeholder is not only a good and simple solution, but it seems to me that any other solution may not be substantially better or more "magical". Also "magic" is generally regarded as a bad idea these days because it implies a lack of transparency. By sticking to the React-Redux way, you are not adding hard to understand code.

Finally, don't expect either React or Redux to know what to do when your app doesn't provide the data that your app requires. Either don't require it or provide it. Creating a simple reusable parent component solves the issue by not requiring the data (and deciding what to do instead, which neither React, nor Redux, nor probably a third party library knows to decide).

Recap: create your own magic. It's simple, quick, and perfectly tuned to your needs.

Comment: I had been struggling with a very similar problem, and `create your own magic` just totally unlocked my understanding. Great answer, and I feel like I genuinely understand the react/redux/react-redux lifecycle better now